# What is the most efficient way to filter a search?

Tags: performance, mongodb

I am working with `node.js` and `mongodb`.

I am going to have a database setup and use [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io) to have real-time updates that will have the db queried again as well or push the new update to the client.

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to filter the database?

Some more information in regards to what is being queried and what the real time updates are:

A document in the database will include information such as an address, city, time, number of packages, name, price.

Filters include city/price/name/time (meaning only to see addresses within the same city, or within the same time period)

Real-time info: includes adding a new document to the database which will essentially update the admin on the website with a notification of a new address added.

**Method 1:** Query the db with the filters being searched?

**Method 2:** Query the db for all searches and then filter it on the client side (Javascript)?

**Method 3:** Query the db for all searches then store it in localStorage then query localStorage for what the filters are?

Trying to figure out what is the fastest way for the user to filter it?
Also, if it is different than what is the most cost effective way, then the most cost effective as well (which I am assuming is less db queries)...

Comment: What's best for you users and the performance of the application? It's not clear what filters on top of a search wold be (as they seem analogous to me). If users start broad, all results returned, then filters applied locally ... then it seems like a client side filter would be appropriate.

Comment: Updated the information to include more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say because we don't see exact conditions of the filter, but in general:

- Mongo can use only 1 index in a query condition. Thus whatever fields are covered by this index can be used in an efficient filtering. Otherwise it might do full table scan which is slow. If you are using an index then you are probably doing the most efficient query. (Mongo can still use another index for sorting though).
- Sometimes you will be forced to do processing on client side because Mongo can't do what you want or it takes too many queries.
- The least efficient option is to store results somewhere just because IO is slow. This would only benefit you if you use them as cache and do not recalculate.
- Also consider overhead and latency of networking. If you have to send lots of data back to the client it will be slower. In general Mongo will do better job filtering stuff than you would do on the client.

According to you if you can filter by addresses within time period then you could have an index that cuts down lots of documents. You most likely need a compound index - multiple fields.

Comment: great explanation, yep I think I am just going to query mongodb once then keep the results in an array and make a new array with the filtered results and show that array and keep replacing that array with what needs to be filtered